# How to fetch and display certain blocks of draft-js editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, draftjs

So I have data saved on the server with the use of `convertToRaw` edited from draft-js, I want to fetch and render that data but only display data that do not have style blocks except(bold, italic, underline)

I also want to add some ellipsis on the rendered text, any example on how to go about this is appreciated

used [This](https://codepen.io/Kiwka/pen/YNYvyG) as my draft-js editor